# How to do Pyjamas like Python in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, pyjamas

Is there any way to have kind of "Jyjamas"(Java thing!!) where python has something callled: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Pyjamas

**Follow up: (native way)**

http://support.awesomium.com/kb/javascript/introduction-to-javascript-c-integration

http://support.awesomium.com/kb/wrappers-integration/ansi-c-api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean like GWT? (there is something ironic about question author's username, I think)

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)?

> HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs". It models HTML
>   documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill
>   out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your "normal"
>   browser.
>
> It has fairly good JavaScript support (which is constantly improving)
>   and is able to work even with quite complex AJAX libraries, simulating
>   either Firefox or Internet Explorer depending on the configuration you
>   want to use.
>
> It is typically used for testing purposes or to retrieve information
>   from web sites.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he is looking for a Java to Javascript compiler.